# TypeORM AfterSave() triggers after creation but when queried, it returns NULL

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have an Entity called `Trip`. The structure is:
[image: db structure]

What I want is whenever a new trip is created, the `room` column should be populated with `${tripId}_${someRandomStringHere}`. So for example, I just created a new trip using this body:

[image: trip_body]

The response should be:
[image: tr]ip response]

The newly created `trip` has the `id` of `15`. So, the response has the `room` valued at `15_4gupvdo0ea408c25ia0qsbh` because again: `${tripId}_${someRandomStringHere}`.

This is working as **expected** whenever I `POST` the request and create the trip. **BUT** whenever I query all the trips created, the `room` property of each trip objects shows `null`!

`Look at the /api/trips:`

[image: trips array]

`room` property is **NULL**. So what the heck I dont understand what is happening.

My `Trip Entity` code is:

```
import { PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, CreateDateColumn, 
UpdateDateColumn, Entity, Unique, ManyToOne, AfterInsert, JoinColumn, getConnection } from 'typeorm'
import { DriverEntity } from 'src/driver/driver.entity';

@Entity('trips')
export class TripEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column()
  destination: string

  @Column('decimal')
  destination_lat: number

  @Column('decimal')
  destination_long: number

  @Column()
  maxPassenger: number

  @Column()
  totalPassenger: number

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  room: string

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date
// --------->HERE: The after insert 
  @AfterInsert()
  async createSocketRoom(): Promise<void> {
    const randomString = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)
    this.room =  `${this.id}_${randomString}`
  }

  // Trip belongs to driver
  // Adds driver_id to trips table
  @ManyToOne(type => DriverEntity, driver => driver.trips)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'driver_id' })
  driver: DriverEntity
}
```

My `Trip Service Code` is:

```
async create(data: CreateTripDTO) {
    const { driver_id } = data
    const driver = await this.driverRepository.findOne({ where: { id: driver_id } })
    const trip = await this.tripRepository.create(data)
    trip.driver = driver

    await this.tripRepository.save(trip)
    return trip
  }
```

I dont think I need to include the `Trip Controller` code but anyway..
I don't know why it is happening because I have my User Entity with @BeforeUpdate and works fine...

**After reading alot of similar github issues, watched youtube tutorials [Hi Ben Awad! :D], I found a somewhat fix.. by using Subscribers**

Actually, I don't know what is the difference of the Listener/Subscriber. Maybe I am doing the wrong usage. Can someone enlighten me please? For example the difference of AfterSave of Entity Listener vs AfterSave of Entity Subscriber. When/Best case  to use? something like that. Anyway back with the `"fix..."`

I created a `Trip Subscriber`:

```
import { EventSubscriber, EntitySubscriberInterface, InsertEvent } from "typeorm";
import { TripEntity } from "src/trip/trip.entity";

@EventSubscriber()
export class TripSubsriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<TripEntity> {
    // Denotes that this subscriber only listens to Trip Entity
    listenTo() {
      return TripEntity
    }

    // Called after entity insertion
    async afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<any>) {
        console.log(`AFTER ENTITY INSERTED: `, event.entity);
        const randomString = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)
        // query the trip with given event.entity
        const trip = await event.manager.getRepository(TripEntity).findOne(event.entity.id)
        // populate the room with desired format
        trip.room = `${trip.id}_${randomString}`
        // save it!
        await event.manager.getRepository(TripEntity).save(trip)
    }

}
```

At first it is not working but after digging for hours again, I need to add a `subscriber` property with the value of the path of my subscribers at the `ormconfig.json` for it to work! 
e.g: `"subscribers": [
    "src/subscriber/*.ts"
  ]`

Again, the `Trip Subscriber` code seems spaghetti to me because I already have the `event.entity` object but I do not know how to update it without the need of querying and updating it using `event.manager.getRepository()`. Please can someone fix this code for me? the proper way of doing it?

**NOW, It is working!**
the request body:
[image: the request body]

the /api/trips res:
[image: res]

My questions are:

1. Why whenever I use that method methoud subscriber, it is not working. Is it not the proper way to do it? The why is it in the docs? Or for other use case?
2. Do I really have to use subscriber for it to achieve? Thats so many steps.

I came from Rails. So having to create files/subscribers just to do it somewhat tiring. Unlike ActiveRecord's `after_save` callback it is very easy..

PS. I'm new to nest-js and typeorm

Answer (score 6):

`@AfterInsert` method will just modify your JS object after inserting into DB is done. So thats reason why is your code not working. You have to use `@BeforeInsert` decorator. `BeforeInsert` will modify your JS entity/object before inserting/saving into DB.

Comment: But if I use @BeforeInsert decorator, **this.id** will result to undefine because the id is not created yet. So I cannot '${this.id}_${randomStringHere}'

Comment: Sorry I see now. So in this case you have to use subscribers sorry. For more info about this problem check https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3563 or https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1705

Comment: I think docs should be updated each difference... AfterInsert in Listener vs in Subscriber. When to use each, etc

Comment: @vlapo21 Can you update your answer to add a note about subscriber ? I think not everyone watches the comments and it's very interesting information.

Comment: What is the difference between the two? Is it okay to run queries inside listeners/subscribers? How can I abort the whole operation? For example if my password hashing function throws an error how should handle it?

Answer (score 3):

What it looks like is happening with your `AfterInsert` is that you are creating the random room string just fine, but you are not saving the value to the database, only using the return of the id so that you can create the string. What you could do in your `AfterInsert` is run the `save()` function from the `EntityManager` or `RepositoryManger` once more and commit the value to the database, similar to what you have happening in you `Subscriber`. I haven't dived too deep into the `Subscriber`/`Listener` vs `Before-/AfterInsert` decorators, so I can't give a deeper answer to your questions.

If you'd rather not make two commits to the database, you can always do a query for the most recent id and increment it by 1 (thus, matching what the new objects id *should* be) with something like

```
const maxId = await this.tripRepository.findOne({select: ['id'], order: {id: "DESC"} });
const trip = await this.tripRepository.create(data);
const randomString = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)
this.room =  `${maxId + 1}_${randomString}`
trip.driver = driver
await this.tripRepository.save(trip)
```

It's a little clunky to look at, but it doesn't require two writes to the database (though you'll definitely need to ensure that after creation room and trip have the same id).

Your last option would be to create a Trigger in your database that does the same thing as your JavaScript code.

Comment: I was thinking also if having the update the data after saving it will be a heavy task to the database because it will be two write. So for u, it is not advisable to update the db after saving the record?

Comment: Thanks for your code. Will surely replace my subscriber to use this instead. Anyone can please enlighten me why are the use cases of Entity subscriber please?

Answer (score -2):

You just use "this.save()" after all in createSocketRoom() function

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUY8n.png my query after use that!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post an image with code for the solution, post your full answer in here. Read this article for information about how answer a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer