# TypeORM eager relations in afterInsert and afterUpdate

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

In TypeORM, I have a subscriber (class implementing EntitySubscriberInterface) which listens on `afterInsert` and `afterUpdate` events. Here is a minimal entity to reproduce my problem:

```js
@Entity()
export class MainEntity {
  @ManyToOne(type => Target, { eager: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'targetId' })
  target: Target;
  @Column()
  targetId: string;
}
```

The eager relation works (loads) when using `mainEntity.find()`, but if I use:

```js
   mainEntity.save({targetId: 'valid_id'}).then((result) => console.log(result))
```

The relation for `.target` is not resolved, neither in the `then()` callback or in the `afterInsert()` event listener. The `targetId` field has the correct value, but `target` is undefined.

Is there a way to tell `.save()` to load eager relations or do I need to get back the entity from the database using its ID in order to get them?

I also tried to use `insert()` instead of `save()` just in case it was a problem with `save()`, to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```js
  async afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<any>) {
    // User.role eager relation
    let entity: User = event.entity;
    entity = await event.manager.getRepository(User).findOne(entity.id);
    const role: Role = entity.role;
  }
```

Or use `event.manager` only (w/o `getRepository`, but idk what's the difference cause this problem).

If use manager, need to save the entity again before retrieve it.
Otherwise `event.manager.findOne(entity.id);` would throw error.

```js
  async afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<any>) {
    let entity: User = event.entity;
    await event.manager.save(entity);
    entity = await event.manager.findOne(entity.id);
    const role: Role = entity.role;
  }
```

Reference from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56484522/15605048) and the github issue link in the comment.